Chern connection and Levi-Civita connection
It is stated on Voisin's book in complex algebraic geometry that on a Kahler manifold, the Chern connection and the Levi--Civita connection coincides on $T_X$. I wonder what this exactly means, as this claims a complex connection equals a real connection.
My guess is the following: Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle, $\nabla$ be a real connection, and $\nabla'$ be a complex connection. Then to say $\nabla$ is the same as $\nabla'$ means the map
\begin{equation}
\nabla\colon E \to E \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \Omega_{M,\mathbb{R}} = \nabla'\colon E \to E \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \Omega_{M,\mathbb{C}} \simeq E \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \Omega_{M,\mathbb{R}}.
\end{equation}
In concrete terms, it means $\nabla_{X} s = \nabla'_{X}s$ for any real vector field $X$.
Is my interpretation correct?

Why real vector field? Real connection? The terminology is misleading and confusing. Just think of the underlying (real) smooth manifold structure, forgetting that you have the holomorphic structure. Interpret the Kähler structure in terms of the underlying Riemannian metric.

@TedShifrin I agree the terminology is misleading and confusing. But to my understanding, Chern connection is a complex connection on complex vector bundles while Levi--Civita connection is a real connection on real vector bundles. So that is the reason I ask this question and want a clarification.

Levi-Civita is, yes, a connection on the tangent bundle — only — of a Riemannian manifold. But you just forget about the complex/holomorphic structure on the complex tangent bundle. The hermitian metric gives a Riemannian metric. But real vector field has a totally different meaning. So have you tried to write down some calculations?
